# How can I make my web server serve Java, Python and Perl out of the same directory?

Tags: linux

I have a java application, but I also have python vs perl code in the same directory. How can I run such a structure? Or does it make sense to run it?

Comment: We need much more detail. Run it how? Are you talking about a web app? What are you doing now? Have you run into problems? What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: Oh sorry. I mean "how can i run ?" with apache or nginx

for example: http://localhost/one.pl
http://localhost/two.jsp

etc..

Comment: I've updated the title of the question to reflect this.

Comment: Still unclear. _Where_ do you want to run it - on the server or on the client? How is "the same directory" relevant? You mean a physical same directory, or you mean from the same URL?